# error "Reading outside memory" in hmac_sha1(prf_data)‏

Tags: java, c, ubuntu, out-of-memory, contiki

I am trying to test some methods (mainly session resumption) to IKEv.2 inside the Ipsec protocol, using Contiki OS as implemented by the Cooja simulation environment.

I need your help to assist me incorporate the session resumption protocol code in C, so that I can resume my simulation.

I tried my best to develop the code, but every time I try to run it, it always gives me the same error " reading out of memory"

I trace the error in IPsec and IKEv.2 protocol code that I download it from this like https://github.com/vjutvik/Contiki-IPsec

and found the error appear when call **hmac_sha1(prf_data);** function. the error message is  "Reading outside memory: 0xfa8b6".

the file path of this function is: contiki-ipsec\core\net\ipsec\ike\prf.c

```
/**    
  * PRF as defined in the RFC    
  */    
void prf(sa_prf_transform_type_t prf_type, prf_data_t *prf_data)    
{    
  switch (prf_type) {
    case SA_PRF_HMAC_SHA1:         // MUST    
    hmac_sha1(prf_data);    
    break;

    case SA_PRF_AES128_CBC:      // SHOULD+    
    PRINTF(IPSEC "Error: Not implemented\n");    
    break;

    default:    
    PRINTF(IPSEC "Error: Unknown PRF request\n");    
  }      
}
```

---

the code function  hmac_sha1(prf_data);

the file path of this function is: contiki-ipsec\core\lib\hmac-sha1\hmac-sha1.c

```
/**    
 * Performs HMAC-SHA1-96. Call this function from your program.    
 *    
 * @param out     Output from HMAC-SHA1-96 (must be at least 96/8=12 bytes)    
 * @param key     The key to use    
 * @param keylen  The length of the key    
 * @param data    The data to hash    
 * @param datalen The length of the data    
 */    
//void hmac_sha1_96( uint16_t datalen, uint8_t * out, uint8_t * key, uint8_t keylen, uint8_t * data )    
void hmac_sha1( hmac_data_t *hmac_data )    
{    
  uint8_t * out=hmac_data->out;    
  uint8_t * key= (uint8_t *) hmac_data->key;    
  uint8_t keylen=hmac_data->keylen;    
  uint8_t * data=hmac_data->data;    
  uint16_t datalen=hmac_data->datalen;           
  dy_printf( "Data after %d %d %d %d %d\n", (int)out, (int)key,(int)keylen,(int)data, (int)datalen );    
    // Variables    
    uint8_t padded_key[ SHA1_B ];    
    uint8_t padded_key_xor_ipad[ SHA1_B ];    
    uint8_t sentence_a[ SHA1_B + datalen ];    
    uint8_t hash_output_a[ SHA1_L ];   
    uint8_t padded_key_xor_opad[ SHA1_B ];    
    uint8_t sentence_b[ SHA1_B + SHA1_L ];    
    uint8_t hash_output_b[ SHA1_L ];            
    init();            
    // Hash overlength keys    
    if( keylen > SHA1_B ){    
        hash_sha1( padded_key, key, keylen ); // Assumes SHA1_L <= SHA_B    
        create_padded_key( padded_key, padded_key, SHA1_L ); // Adds the zeros    
    }    
    else{    
        create_padded_key( padded_key, key, keylen );    
    }            
    dy_printf("datelen:%d\n",(int)datalen);    
    PRINT_BUF("padded_key",padded_key,SHA1_B);            
    xor_array( padded_key_xor_ipad, padded_key, ipad, SHA1_B );    
    PRINT_BUF("padded_key_xor_ipad",padded_key_xor_ipad,SHA1_B);            
    merge_arrays( sentence_a, padded_key_xor_ipad, SHA1_B, data, datalen );    
    PRINT_BUF("sentence_a",sentence_a,SHA1_B+datalen);            
    hash_sha1( hash_output_a, sentence_a, SHA1_B + datalen );    
    PRINT_BUF("hash_output_a",hash_output_a,SHA1_L);            
    xor_array( padded_key_xor_opad, padded_key, opad, SHA1_B );    
    PRINT_BUF("padded_key_xor_opad",padded_key_xor_opad,SHA1_B);           
    merge_arrays( sentence_b, padded_key_xor_opad, SHA1_B, hash_output_a, SHA1_L );         
  hash_sha1(hmac_data->out, sentence_b, SHA1_B + SHA1_L );    
    // Old truncate code    
    //hash_sha1( hash_output_b, sentence_b, SHA1_B + SHA1_L );    
    //truncate( out, hash_output_b, 96/8 );    
}
```

---

**I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32-bit**

**gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4**

Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

**msp430-gcc (GCC) 4.7.2 20120920 (mspgcc dev 20120911)**

Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

I using Contiki-IPsec 2.7 OS, also I’m using Wismote in Cooja simulation

**Edit**:

the type defined of the pointers in the functions above is

```
typedef struct {
  uint8_t *out; 
  const uint8_t *key; 
  uint8_t keylen;
  uint8_t *data; 
  uint16_t datalen;
} hmac_data_t;
```

and the other type defined

```
typedef hmac_data_t prf_data_t;
```

Any idea to overcome this issue is highly appreciated.

Thanking you in advanced.

Comment: Is `prf_data_t` really compatible with `hmac_data_t`?

Comment: I edit my question to add the type of pointer that you mention, yes it the same I think .... what you think? and thanks for your comment